# Custom Listview(or Adapter) that allows updating a row instead of adding one. (Android)

Tags: android-listview

I have a listview. 
Now, i'm using switch-case, where i'm comparing `getView()` method's `position` with an id obtained from the server in the form of JSON response.
Suppose the id is `myobjectarraylist.get(poisition).getIDForComparison`.
**Myadapter.java**

```
 ArrayList<MyObject> myobjectarraylist;
        int counter = 0;
     @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        switch(myobjectarraylist.get(poisition).getIDForComparison){

        case x:

        if (myobjectarraylist.get(position).getIDForComparison) == myobjectarraylist.get(nextposition).getIDForComparison){
        "update the same row by concatenating new text with the exisiting"
        }
        else{
        "insert next row"
        }


        }
    }
```

So, basically i need to keep collecting the information from my json object in the same row until the `myobjectarraylist.get(poisition).getIDForComparison` is same for current and next position. if not, i want to allow the addition of a new row.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you mean you want to change the data in it like text, image, color or change the background colour of the row, remove it etc ...

Comment: One more thing why are you doing a case and a if, looks like a possible code smell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic processing should never be done inside the getView Method as it is called multiple random times which leads to inconsistency in the conditionals returning false even though it is a truthy statement.

Assuming that your `MyAdapter.java` extends `BaseAdapter` 
There are two other methods in the `BaseAdapter` that can be overridden

1. [BaseAdapter.getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount())
2. [BaseAdapter.getItemViewType(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount())

Your logic should be placed inside `getItemViewType(int position)`, and the corresponding view modifications should be done inside it.

`getViewTypeCount()` - Returns the number of types of Views that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup). Each type represents a set of views that can be converted in getView(int, View, ViewGroup). If the adapter always returns the same type of View for all items, this method should return 1

Hope this helps